# Linespacing exception for tables and itemize and enumerate

Tags: tables, enumerate, itemize, line-spacing

With

```
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
```

I am able to set the linespacing of my whole document.
But I want to have my tables and itemize/enumerate of normal linespacing. How can I do this? (I know I can do this at each individual table).

Ideally I want to do this before the \begin{document}

Comment: [Different line spacing for body text than inside tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/350222/134144) and [Change line spacing for normal text, but not in tabular or verse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26167/134144) might be helpful.

Comment: With the help of the `itemsep` option introduced by th e`enumitem` package you can control the spacing between adjacent items in an itemize or enumerate list.

Comment: @leandriis why not use `\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}}` and the like with `\usepackage{etoolbox}`, seems easier than playing with the `itemsep` option.

Comment: @Skillmon: good point.

Answer (score 1):

For your tabular environments, the answer is easy:  just change your `\arraystretch` *after* you change your `\baselinestretch`:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
```

Notice that it's half of what `\baselinestretch` is; so since `\baselinestretch` is 2, you need to set `\arraystretch` to 0.5 to get it back to 1.

Your `itemize` lengths are a bit tricker.  Here, I think your best option is the `etoolbox` package, which lets you manipulate what happens when an environment is invoked without having to alter the environment itself.  Here, I'd use the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
   \AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\baselineskip=1.25em}
```

Or whatever value you think makes it look best.    The inter-item spacing would be double, though, unless you also used `enumitem` (the package) to change `itemsep`, as suggested in one of the comments:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
   \setlist{itemsep=-0.5em}
```

You can massage the spacing until you get what you want, but this seems to be just about right.  Here's my complete example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[width=7in,height=10in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\baselineskip=1.25em}
\usepackage{enumitem}
   \setlist{itemsep=-0.5em}

\parindent=4em
\parskip=1em
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular}{ll}
One & line \\
Two & lines \\
Three & lines \\
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{itemize}
\item One thing here to see what happens.
\item A second thing here; and I'll make sure this one
covers more than one line so that we can confirm the right
thing still happens.  It's important, after all.
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

(`geometry` was included just to make it all fit on one page.)  And here's the result:

[image: Complete document with desired effects.]